# Suspicious unknown blog post at WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, security, spam

a few days back I noticed a few things on my WordPress site

1. One ad in the header and one in the footer
2. Hundreds of new blog posts which I didn't post

Here are the things I did to prevent this from happening anymore

1. Updated my server password
2. Removed links from header and footer.php
3. I also found a lot of xml files under **sitefiles** folder, I deleted them all. All those files had content from the same brand.

A few more things to notice:

- As I came back after doing the above steps I found two more posts posted a few minutes ago which I didn't post.
- Also, after changing my server password yesterday, I got an email today that someone is trying to access my server and is blocked by the service.
- My website.com/index.php also had a link inside
- My wp-includes/wp-db.php had the code below
  `/**
    WordPress DB Class
    Original code from {@link http://php.justinvincent.com Justin 
  Vincent (justin@visunet.ie)}
    @package WordPress
    @subpackage Database
    @since 0.71
  */`

I have one more WordPress website on this server which is affected in the same way. The other is also having unknown posts **having no users mentioned in author tab**.

Please, let me know what can be the possible reason/reason and how can I protect my blog and server.
My server is **namecheap**.

Thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to do with your passwords. Some script kiddie uses a vulnerability in the one of the wordpress plugins you use. Nothing you can do against that except taking the site offline until you have identified which plugin (or even the core) has that vulnerability. Wordpress has a long history of being the most vulnerably and insecure CMS flatform in use.

Comment: Thanks, @arkascha. But I'm curious why this is happening in both sites on the server? If it is because of the plugin it should be on one site only. 

Also, I found lines of code in header, footer, and index.php which I think are not added through any plugin or i can be wrong.

Comment: A plugin is software installed into the core of the wordpress site. That certainly should affect _all_ "sites" hosted in a CMS.

Comment: The fact that your php files got altered indicate another _huge_ security gap you apparently left open: that indicates that those files are writable by the actual php code itself, so by the php engine. That is against all basic security measures one takes when operating some web software: the implementation should _never_ be able to alter itself!

Comment: Thanks for helping. Let me try to fix permissions.

Answer (score 0):

This code is just the default code of all wordpress version added, No need to wory much about this. You must find strange function in the plugins and themes to identify the vulnerability of your wordpress site. Most backdoor and spam code come along with the Plugins and themes that come from free download site, none wordpress repository.